# What is the proper way to handle string encoding in haskell?

Tags: haskell, encoding, utf-8

I'm on windows w/ codepage 949.. and Excel and Notepad.exe will happily save files with `cp949` encoding.

On python dealing with them isn't a pain - with `str.encode` and `str.decode`.

recently I've discovered Haskell, and it seems like there is more than one way to manipulate strings. real world haskell tells me to use `ByteString` for efficient IO, but I don't see a way to switch between encodings I use.

I have to read files that are not in UTF8 encoding, and write them back in their original encoding. most of them will be `cp949`.

Internally my haskell source will be in `utf8`.

It wasn't that hard in python, with the principle of `str` for IO, `unicode`for processing, but on haskell they even lack built-in `cp949` support.

so the question is - how do I do IO over files in various encodings? I have to read, convert, process, and write them.

---

### edit:

I tried both options and .. it seems the state of text conversion on windows is abysmal.

**text-icu**

pros:

- `text` seems to be modern, high-level choice for text manipulation
- easy to install on windows: just grab [icu binaries](http://apps.icu-project.org/icu-jsp/downloadPage.jsp?ver=52.1&base=c&svn=release-52-1) and point `include` and `lib` folders when installing `text-icu` with `cabal install`.

cons:

- converters are IO
- can't initialize a converter multiple times(something to do with thread safety, I get runtime error)
- does not work with `Lazy` bytestrings
- requires >20mb dlls

**iconv**

pros:

- no monads

cons:

- a pain to install on windows
- some decoding failures when I tried on larger files.. usually for `iconv`(the command-line, or dll) you have to feed unbuffered input to get proper output but haskell's binding seems to only work with lazy bytestrings

Comment: I'm not aware of `cp949` encoding for Haskell but whenever you have to deal with text encodings is usually better to work with the [`text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package instead of `bytestring`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Convert` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu-0.6.3.7/docs/Data-Text-ICU-Convert.html) of the [`text-icu` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu) for encodings not directly supported by `text`.

Assuming you already got the encoded `ByteString`, you would do something like this:

```
import qualified Data.Text.ICU.Convert as Convert

decodeCP949 :: ByteString -> IO Text
decodeCP949 bs = do
    conv <- Convert.open "cp949" Nothing
    return $ Convert.toUnicode conv bs

encodeCP949 :: Text -> IO ByteString
encodeCP949 t = do
    conv <- Convert.open "cp949" Nothing
    return $ Convert.fromUnicode conv t
```

The `IO` here is a bit annoying here. I think this is a case where using `unsafePerfomIO` would to obtain the converter once would be alright.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Codec.Text.IConv` module in the `iconv` package:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iconv-0.4.1.2/docs/Codec-Text-IConv.html

The `convert` function will convert from one encoding to another, so you can convert a CP949 ByteString to a UTF8 ByteString (and then to Text if you want.)

And you can also reverse the process (Text -> UTF8 ByteString -> CP949 ByteString)

Here is some example code I found on github:

https://github.com/wookay/da/blob/master/haskell/fun/test_encode.hs

Comment: I didn't know that package. It's really handy when you just need quick encoding conversion.